# Speed-up Pandas Dataframe insert into a Postgres DB using SQLAlchemy

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I have a postgres table with about 100k rows. I extracted this dataset and applied some transformation resulting in a new pandas dataframe containing 100K rows. Now I want to load this dataframe as a new table in the database. I used `to_sql` to convert the dataframe to a postgres table using SQLAlchemy connection. However, this is very slow and takes several hours. How can I use SQLAlchemy to speed up dataframe insert into database table? I want to increase insert speed from several hours to few seconds? Can someone help me with this?

I have searched through other similar questions on Stackoverflow. Most of them converts data to a csv file and then use `copy_from` for sql. I am looking towards a solution using SQLAlchemy bulk insert statement with pandas dataframe.

Here is a small version of my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import * 
url = 'postgresql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'
url = url.format(user, password, localhost, 5432, db)
con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(url, client_encoding='utf8')
# I have a dataframe named 'df' containing 100k rows. I use the following code to insert this dataframe into the database table.
df.to_sql(name='new_table', con=con, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: it would be easier to get an answer if you present a small workable example of code, for example what arguments do you pass to to_sql() method?

Comment: @suvy I have edited my question to include a sample code.

Comment: wonder if this is quick way to test if it is the server, try to use a file based database engine = create_engine('sqlite:///myfile.db') , is this equally slow?

Answer (score 0):

Try below model if the pandas version is above 0.24

> ## Alternative to_sql() *method* for DBs that support COPY FROM import csv from io import StringIO
>
> def psql_insert_copy(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
>       # gets a DBAPI connection that can provide a cursor
>       dbapi_conn = conn.connection
>       with dbapi_conn.cursor() as cur:
>           s_buf = StringIO()
>           writer = csv.writer(s_buf)
>           writer.writerows(data_iter)
>           s_buf.seek(0)
>
> ```
>     columns = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(k) for k in keys)
>     if table.schema:
>         table_name = '{}.{}'.format(table.schema, table.name)
>     else:
>         table_name = table.name
>
>     sql = 'COPY {} ({}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV'.format(
>         table_name, columns)
>     cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
> ```
>
> chunksize = 10 **4 # it depends on your server configuration. for my case 10**4 ~10**5 is OK.
>   df.to_sql('tablename',con=con, if_exists='replace',method=psql_insert_copy ,chunksize= chunksize)

if you use above psql_insert_copy mode and your postgresql server is work normally, you should enjoy fly speed.

Here is my ETL speed. Average 280~300K tuple per batch(in seconds).
[image]